# set parent=%CD%\.. doesnt evaluate to the folder above as expected

Tags: windows, batch-file

In the batch file below I get current path.. How do I get it to print one level above "current path" ?

```
set current=%CD%
set parent=%CD%\..
echo %parent%
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should return the full path to the parent folder of the *current active directory*

```
for %%a in (..\) do set "parent=%%~fa"
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no good way to do this, other than changing the directory temporarily.

Fortunately, there's an easy way to go back a directory and then switch again:

```
set current=%CD%
pushd ..
set parent=%CD%
popd
echo %parent%
```

This uses the `pushd` and `popd` commands, which are nice.

Note that this will result in parent equaling current if you are on the root directory (EG `C:`), but the old script does the same.

Answer (score 0):

There is no variable for one level above your current path. To get the parent folder, simply cd back one directory, set the parent variable to that current directory, and if desired, cd back to your original directory. Like this:

```
set current=%CD%
cd..
set parent=%CD%
cd %current%
echo %parent%
pause
```

Answer (score 0):

Run this from a first level folder or higher.

```
@echo off
for %%a in ("%cd%") do echo "%%~dpa"
pause
```